# HTML5 Video background not showing for Safari or IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, safari

I've tried applying the fixes from other forum posts but none resolved this puzzle.

[This video background](http://celebritysites.com/beta/pike/) does not work on Safari or IE.  This is the current code:

```
<video controls preload="preload" id="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted >
  <source src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/video/pike.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/video/pike.mov" type="video/mov">
  <source src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/video/pike.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Would you additionally be able to paste the generated source code so I can see what it looks like once the PHP has been run.

Comment: .mov files are for Quicktime plugins(plugin on safari, activex in IE). see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380695/how-to-open-mov-format-video-in-html-video-tag... Quicktime has security issues (NSA warnings)... and you should avoid continuing publishing in that format... Safari supports webm, so you can just remove the source element.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using a higher version of IE and Safari, because the tag video works only on version 3.5 above on Safari and a version above 9.0 in IE.