# HTML5 video not playing on Samsung S8, Samsung browser

Tags: video, mobile, samsung-mobile

The video works fine on all desktop, and mobile Chrome. However, while using the Samsung browser, after clicking the play button, the video only shows the video poster distorted and doesn't play.

I've tried various JavaScript solutions to force play, but can't seem to target any elements here to even fire JavaScript alerts. Any suggestions or help is appreciated!

My original code is as follows: I currently have no JavaScript, just this HTML.

`<div id="video" class="embed-container">
  <video  class="home-video" controls  poster="http://mytestsite.com/video_cover.jpg">
    <source src="http://mytestsite.com/Video-V2-720p.mov">
    </source>
</div>`

Comment: I tried to replicate this but I couldn't get a .mov video file to play in any browser I tried - it's not a supported type?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40514024/396246

Comment: That was the cause. I'm going to update my answer. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was switching to from .mov to .mp4. Apparantly as of now, .mov is not a supported file type for some devices running Samsung Internet browser. Hope this helps someone.